# How to select an entity with a named item in their offhand in Minecraft 1.14?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a repeating command block set to "always active" running this command.

```
/effect give @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:-106b,id:"minecraft:stick", tag:{display:{Name:"Speed Stick Deodorant"}}}]}] minecraft:speed 1 7 true
```

In my offhand, I'm holding a stick given to me via this command:

```
/give @p stick{display:{Name:"\"Speed Stick Deodorant\""},Enchantments:[{id:unbreaking,lvl:10}]} 1
```

The output on the repeating command block says "No entity was found". What's wrong here?

I also tried giving myself the stick without enchantments to see if that was a problem. Didn't help.

Comment: Is the second \ in the Name bracket supposed to be in the second pair of quotation marks?

Comment: Yes, it is. I don't think anything is wrong with the second line of code, but for some reason, the first line isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

You have different names for the stick. One is escaped and one is not. Without escaping the name it can't be interpreted properly, since it is inside another tag which already interprets the quotes.

Escape the name properly in your `/effect` command and it will work (tested and works for me):

```
/effect give @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:-106b,id:"minecraft:stick", tag:{display:{Name:"\"Speed Stick Deodorant\""}}}]}] minecraft:speed 1 7 true
```